# expectation of women sitting next to at least one man

Tags: probability, expected-value, combinatorics

we are given that there are $5 \ men$ and $5 \ women$ are seated randomly in a single circle of chairs. What is the expected number of women sitting next to at least one man?

**My approach**

As we are given 10 seats, we can number them as $S_i$ where $ i∈(1,...,10)$

Here $S_i$ takes the value 1 if there is a woman sitting on seat number $i$ otherwise it takes the value 0.

we can define expectation as  $$E(X)= E(S_1)+...+E(S_{10})$$

to compute the required probability i have used the method
$$E(S_1)= \Pr(S_1 = 1)= 1-\Pr(S_1 = 0)$$ because by symmetry $E(S_1)=...=E(S_{10})$

**answer is coming out to be $25/6$**

Can I solve it in any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution.** To make amend of your approach, let $W_i$ be the event that a woman seats on position $i$, and then define $S_i$ as the indicator function

$$ S_i
= \mathbf{1}_{W_i \cap (W_{i-1} \cap W_{i+1})^c}
= \begin{cases}
1, & \begin{aligned} & \text{if a woman seats on position $i$} \\ & \text{and at least one man sits next to it,} \end{aligned} \\[0.5em]
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} $$

Then the number $X$ of women sitting next to at least one man can be written by $X=\sum_{i=1}^{10} S_i$. Moreover, by the multiplication rule,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(S_i=1)
&= \mathbf{P}(W_i) \mathbf{P}((W_{i-1} \cap W_{i+1})^c \mid W_i) \\
&= \mathbf{P}(W_i) \bigl[ 1 -  \mathbf{P}(W_{i-1} \cap W_{i+1} \mid W_i) \bigr] \\
&= \mathbf{P}(W_i) \bigl[ 1 -  \mathbf{P}(W_{i-1} \mid W_i)\mathbf{P}(W_{i+1} \mid W_i \cap W_{i-1}) \bigr] \\
&= \tfrac{5}{10}\left(1-\tfrac{4}{9}\cdot\tfrac{3}{8}\right) \\
&= \tfrac{5}{12}.
\end{align*}

Therefore it follows that

$$ \mathbf{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \mathbf{P}(S_i=1) = \frac{25}{6}. $$

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution.** Instead, suppose the women are numbered $1, 2, \ldots, 5$ and then let

$$ S'_i
= \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if woman $i$ seats next to at least one man,} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} $$

Then $X = \sum_{i=1}^{5} S'_i$, and

$$ \mathbf{P}(S'_i = 1) = 1 - \mathbf{P}(S'_i = 0) = 1 - \tfrac{4}{9}\cdot\tfrac{3}{8} = \tfrac{5}{6}.  $$

So the answer is

$$\mathbf{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{5} \mathbf{P}(S'_i=1) = \frac{25}{6}. $$